# How do I update a SQL table in batches?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I already spent some time trying to figure this out, but I am still somewhat stuck an I can't really find the solution online as I think I am missing the keywords.

I want to update an SQL tables in batches, meaning I have a few million entries and want to update index 0-999, 1000-1999 step by step to avoid a huge database lock.

This is what I found:

```
DECLARE @Rows INT,
        @BatchSize INT;

SET @BatchSize = 2500;
SET @Rows = @BatchSize;

WHILE (@Rows = @BatchSize)
BEGIN
    UPDATE TOP(@BatchSize) db1
    SET db1.attr = db2.attr
    FROM DB1 db1
    LEFT JOIN DB2 db2
    ON db1.attr2 = db2.attr2

    SET @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT;
END;
```

I simplified my statement a little bit as you can see, but it should still be clear how I approached the whole problem.

However, this thing loops forever, and when looking at the output it changed much more rows than there are in the database.

I checked the same loop with a select statement inside later on and found out that it seems to simply select the first @BatchSize rows of the table on and on, even though I thought it would progress in the index with every iteration.

How can I change this so it actually does progress by @BatchSize indices every iteration instead of simply targeting the same rows everytime?

Comment: `mysql <> tsql`..as the code looks like TSQL, i removed the mysql tag.

Comment: TOP (N) and no order by, could select the same top N - after the update there is nothing which is changing the row to exclude it from the next iteration of Top(N) that I can see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need some limiting factor to decide which rows are hit each loop.  Generally you will use an `id` field.  There are lots of ways to approach it, but here is one way:

```
DECLARE @MinID int = 1;
DECLARE @MaxID int = 2500;
DECLARE @Rows int = 1;
DECLARE @Batchsize int = 2500;

WHILE (@Rows > 0)  -- need greater than 0 to enter loop
BEGIN
       UPDATE db1
       SET db1.attr = db2.attr
       FROM DB1 db1
       LEFT JOIN DB2 db2 ON db1.attr2 = db2.attr2
       WHERE db1.ID BETWEEN @MinID AND @MaxID

SET @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT
SET @MinID = @MinID + @Batchsize
SET @MaxID = @MaxID + @Batchsize

END
```

Replace `db1.ID` with whatever field works best in your table schema.

Note, your approach would work if you had some kind of `WHERE` clause on the update query that prevented the same rows from being returned.

Ex. `UPDATE table SET id = 1 WHERE id = 2` won't pull the same rows in a second execution

Comment: First iteration 0 to 2500, second iteration, 2500 to 5000 - there is a double run on row 2500 (as between is inclusive), although I don't think it will matter for this example, but worth noting.

Answer (score 0):

You are just updating the same rows. Need a `and <>`.

Left join?  If you really want to assign null values then use a separate update.

```
DECLARE @Rows INT,
        @BatchSize INT;

SET @BatchSize = 2500;
SET @Rows = @BatchSize;

WHILE (@Rows = @BatchSize)
BEGIN
    UPDATE TOP(@BatchSize) db1
    SET db1.attr = db2.attr
    FROM DB1 db1
    JOIN DB2 db2
      ON db1.attr2 = db2.attr2 
     AND db1.attr <> db2.attr

    SET @Rows = @@ROWCOUNT;
END;
```

And you can do this:

```
select 1
WHILE (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
BEGIN
    UPDATE TOP(2000) db1
    SET db1.attr = db2.attr
    FROM DB1 db1
    JOIN DB2 db2
      ON db1.attr2 = db2.attr2 
     AND db1.attr <> db2.attr
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using a cte with row_number:

```
DECLARE @BatchSize int = 2500,
        @LastRowUpdated int = 0;
        @Count int


SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM db1;


;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  attr, 
            attr2,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY attr, atrr2) As RN
    FROM db1
)

WHILE @LastRowUpdated < @Count
BEGIN

    UPDATE c
    SET attr = db2.atrr
    FROM CTE c
    LEFT JOIN DB2 ON c.attr2 = db2.attr2
    WHERE c.RN > @LastRowUpdated
    AND c.RN < (@LastRowUpdated +1) * @BatchSize

    SELECT @LastRowUpdated += 1

END
```

This will update 2500 records each step of the loop.

Comment: I think this is best answer. But in With dont work with While. Any idea?

Comment: @LêDuyThứ what do you mean by "With dont work with While?"?

Comment: [A CTE must be followed by a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement that references some or all the CTE columns.] This doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I see. Replace the cte with a table variable and an insert...select statement. That would do the trick.

Comment: Yes right. I thougt your idea, but my table has 70 mil rows. I need update one column in over this table.

Comment: In that case, you might want to try replacing the cte with a derived table.

Comment: Why not just put the cte inside the WHILE loop?

Comment: But why are you increasing the LastRowUpdated by 1 instead of by the BatchSize?

Comment: That's a 5 year old answer, do you really think I can remember what I was thinking about? Probably just a typo